# Javascript dispatchEvent click is not working in IE9 and IE10

Tags: javascript, events, internet-explorer-9, dispatchevent

I'm trying to simulate mouse events like click, mouseover etc on app build in ExtJs. I'm using below code to simulate click,

```
function triggerEvent(element, eventName)
{
    if (document.createEvent)
    {
        var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        evt.initEvent(eventName, true, true);

        return element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}

var btn = document.getElementById("loginButton");

triggerEvent(btn, "click");
```

This works fine on chrome and firefox but never works on IE9 and IE10. If I use btn.fireEvent('onlclick') then it works fine in IE9 (not checked in IE10). document.createEvent is supported in IE9 & IE10 but I'm not sure why my code is not working.

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6838705/924943)

Answer (score 9):

I have had the same issue with custom events some time ago and solved by using the code found in this other question:
[Custom events in IE without using libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342917/custom-events-in-ie-without-using-libraries)

Actually you don't need to use all the code, they are 3 function to use as wrapper for browser compatibility.

But I also suggest you to use the .click method which would solve your problem more easily (at least for normal click)
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp

so just do

```
document.getElementById("loginButton").click();
```

I am pasting here the code by [sergey gospodarets](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1120798/sergey-gospodarets) from the other question, which could be useful.

```
    function triggerEvent(el,eventName){
        var event;
        if(document.createEvent){
            event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
            event.initEvent(eventName,true,true);
        }else if(document.createEventObject){// IE < 9
            event = document.createEventObject();
            event.eventType = eventName;
        }
        event.eventName = eventName;
        if(el.dispatchEvent){
            el.dispatchEvent(event);
        }else if(el.fireEvent && htmlEvents['on'+eventName]){// IE < 9
            el.fireEvent('on'+event.eventType,event);// can trigger only real event (e.g. 'click')
        }else if(el[eventName]){
            el[eventName]();
        }else if(el['on'+eventName]){
            el['on'+eventName]();
        }
    }
    function addEvent(el,type,handler){
        if(el.addEventListener){
            el.addEventListener(type,handler,false);
        }else if(el.attachEvent && htmlEvents['on'+type]){// IE < 9
            el.attachEvent('on'+type,handler);
        }else{
            el['on'+type]=handler;
        }
    }
    function removeEvent(el,type,handler){
        if(el.removeventListener){
            el.removeEventListener(type,handler,false);
        }else if(el.detachEvent && htmlEvents['on'+type]){// IE < 9
            el.detachEvent('on'+type,handler);
        }else{
            el['on'+type]=null;
        }
    }

    var _body = document.body;
    var customEventFunction = function(){
        alert('triggered custom event');
    }
    // Subscribe
    addEvent(_body,'customEvent',customEventFunction);
    // Trigger
    triggerEvent(_body,'customEvent');
```

Comment: Yup, the document.getElementById("loginButton").click(); works perfectly

Comment: where is the htmlEvents object coming from?

Answer (score -3):

Without reading your question I can tell you fireEvent works even on IE11 for e.g. `WMP.fireEvent("onmouseup")` where WMP is [my] windowsmediaplayer object element....

And worse trouble, `if(attachEvent)` throws an error instead of taking the `false` out...sometimes.